# Know its been busy but how long should a transaction be pending

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Sorry for my ignorance..i'm completely new to bitcoin.
I sent small amount .£50 from blockchain to bitcoin 3 days ago .just to see how it works.it has shown in my bitcoin wallet as pending so i figure i've sent it correctly. 
I realize its been a bit busy lately and im in no rush, but have i just lost £50 into thin air. !

https://blockchain.info/tx/c6848b6bad00d1150aee2c76bee045e074ba58862d0c864e53a826e4c84b188d

Comment: If this doesn't work out...back to physical gold for me !

Comment: The transaction was confirmed hours ago.